# Can I use an EQU in z/OS HL/ASM for a value in a DC?

Tags: assembly, zos

I am trying to figure out the syntax to assign a computed constant to a constant.
I want to assign the fixed value 13 to JACK. I tried as follows:

```
FRED EQU 6
JOE  EQU 7
JILL EQU FRED+JOE
JACK DC F(JILL)
     END
```

But I got an invalid delimiter. I can see that JILL is indeed 13, and if I make this

```
FRED EQU 6
JOE  EQU 7
JILL EQU FRED+JOE
JACK DC A(JILL)
     END
```

it 'works', but I want JACK to be a full word, not an address (I guess it's 4 bytes in either case, but it seems like 'false advertising')

Comment: I think you'll find that many folks writing assembler on a daily basis tend to use A(x) more than F'x'...looking over my own code, I almost never use F when I can use A instead. I suppose it's a style thing, but I tend to use AL1(0), AL2(0), AL3(0) or A(0) for one-byte, two-byte, three-byte or fullword constants. I also like that I can code things like A(X'FF') - seems more readable for me, as well as dealing with the issue you describe of setting a fullword to an assembler-computed value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second method is valid, and there is nothing wrong with it.

EQUs are 'kind-of' addresses when you take into consideration that we use the `LA Rx,EquLabel` instruction - which is a Load Address (syntactically, at least) - to load its value, and we use `EQU *` for the current (relative) address in assembly code. Nevertheless, they are plain integer values in the end. We also use EQU to define aliases for register numbers as in `R15 EQU 15`.

A plain `JACK DC A(Jill)` does the same as defining a full-word.

N.b. You can also define other lengths using `AL1`, `AL2`, and `AL3`. The invalid delimiter in `JACK DC F(JILL)` is issued because `DC F` requires quotation marks as value delimiters, not parentheses, but the quotation marks keep the assembler from replacing the EQU label with its value, so we can't use an equ to define a fullword, or any other type except an address constant for that matter.

`A(Label)` - with parentheses instead of quotation marks - is kind of an "emergency exit" for cases like yours; I personally would still code `FRED DC F'6'` and `JOE DC F'7'`, which is more straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

A(...) by default generates a 4-byte address, i.e. a full word.  If you want to control the length explicitly though, you can:  ala  JACK DC **AL4**(JILL)
Part of your issue is that the argument of an EQU assembler instruction is *by definition* an address, either absolute, relocatable, or complexly relocatable so the effective value of a resolved EQU instruction is also an address.  Coding DC F'an address' won't work because it's a type mismatch.
Reference:  https://www-40.ibm.com/servers/resourcelink/svc00100.nsf/pages/zOSV2R3sc264940?OpenDocument

Comment: I disagree. The manual you mention states on page 181f: 

"The EQU instruction assigns absolute or relocatable *values* to symbols."

Otherwise the very-much used  R15 EQU 15 could never work (see my post before).

EQU stands for Equate, and a series of digits has no "tag" or anything that tags it as an address. In practice, naturally, EQU often means an address, but not necessarily. You could even code ALLFOUR EQU 16 then use that in an ICM R8,ALLFOUR,MYBUFFER...

Comment: What, exactly, do you think an "absolute or relocatable value" is???  The word "relocatable" itself SCREAMS address.   But, go ahead and think whatever you like.

Comment: Yes, relocatable may be, and absolute screams the opposite - NOT an address. Otherwise, the text would say address instead of value if it were to convey that meaning. By the way, ASM also accepts MyString EQU 'XYZ' - Is that an address? Moreover, ASM ist not at all interested in addresses, only in offsets. And, as I said before, what is you opinion on R1 EQU 1 - is that an address?